# Can vibrations be used to reduce friction?

Tags: friction, resonance

[This lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-Bn70PpbrM) by Julius Miller got me wondering if acoustic resonance (or vibration in general) can be used to reduce friction (or stiction). The answer seems to be no based on the observation that my speakers require the same amount of force to move when on or off. Is it correct that acoustic resonance doesn't reduce friction and if this is correct why not?

Comment: I think of worm gear normally force isn't transmitted from pinion to worm. Buy if a vibration can. Also I think of machines which use vibrations for stuff to move, there is no angular net movement but it can induce a net angular velocity on parts inside. I think the vibration uses objects momentum to reduce normal force?

Comment: Think the core of it is acceleration describing the vibration.

Comment: google the term 'dither' which is used in feedback control to help prevent stiction in bearings and contacting surfaces. If lubricating fluids have any degree of *thixotrophic* behavior, vibrating may help decrease viscosity, resistance to motion.

Comment: This video shows something similar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ0lhHzgSvo

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of friction, the amount of vibration, and the direction.

Extreme example: if you are balancing on a pogo stick on a windy day, the wind won't move you (static friction too great). However, if you start jumping (vibrating), there comes a point where you have no contact with the ground and the wind can move you.

In the case of static friction, if you can (temporarily) reduce the normal force, you can most definitely reach a point where you lower the minimum force needed to move. However, in the case of dynamic friction, the average normal force will be unchanged. Depending on the frequency, you may or may not notice that the friction is changing.

Comment: Could vibrations be a reason for the initial large force required to overcome friction?

Comment: @marshalcraft I don’t think so. It’s a combination of micro surface features and attractive forces between the surfaces. Once in motion, the “intimate” contact that is possible in the static situation is reduced and so the effect of attraction is less.